# Two separate case statements resulting in error

Tags: sql

Before I just had

```
CASE obf.field_type
                WHEN 'Select One'
                        THEN obsc.label
                ELSE ocd.data
                END AS value
```

And it worked.
Now I would like to add in a case where I am checking if ga.bases is null then use ga1.bases, if ga.bases is not null then use ga.bases. So I made this statement

```
CASE ga.bases
        WHEN  ga.bases IS NULL THEN
            ga1.bases
        ELSE
            ga.bases
        END
```

Now When I put these two together they do not work as follows:

```
CASE obf.field_type
                WHEN 'Select One'
                        THEN obsc.label
                ELSE ocd.data
                END AS value

        CASE ga.bases
        WHEN  ga.bases IS NULL THEN
            ga1.bases
        ELSE
            ga.bases
        END
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "CASE"
LINE 12:   CASE ga.bases
           ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "CASE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 298
```

I do not understand why it would be wrong or how I would go about fixing this problem

Comment: Have you forgotten you put a comma between both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a comma between the two case statements.

Also, the second case looks a little weird. You can't test for NULL using that form of case, try this:

```
CASE
  WHEN ga.bases IS NULL THEN ga1.bases
  ELSE ga.bases
END
```

Note there's no value after the `CASE`.

But even easier would be:

```
COALESCE(ga.bases, ga1.bases)
```

Comment: Correct only if he wants two columns, i'm not sure since he provided only one alias.

Comment: If I want only one column to appear how would I change it?

Comment: maybe concatenate the two values. you haven't said what RDBMS you're using, but `concat(a, b)` for mysql or `a || b` for postgres for example might work for you. it's not clear that you want one value, because you've left `AS VALUE` after the first `CASE`, but that wouldn't be allowed if you were joining the two values together (that `AS VALUE` would come at the end)

Comment: The COALESCE ended up giving me what I wanted but the it still displays the other two columns. Column 1 = Tree Column two = Park the COALESCE give me the output I disire but the other two columns are still there. Is there a way to get rid of the other two columns and still have the COALESCE work

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need a comma:

```
    (CASE obf.field_type
          WHEN 'Select One'
                    THEN obsc.label
          ELSE ocd.data
     END) AS value,
    (CASE ga.bases
          WHEN  ga.bases IS NULL
          THEN ga1.bases
          ELSE ga.bases
    END)
```